# How to update Actions Project Category to use Actions SDK

Tags: actions-on-google

While creating a new project in Actions on Google console. You see the following information

"Get started on building by choosing a category or skip to choose later"

I used the skip option and now I am unable to update my project to use Actions SDK.

Can anyone help me on how to change this configuration to start using Actions SDK in an existing project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That page doesn't actually do anything for the project - I usually skip it, no matter what I'm doing.

Once you have a project created you are able to [use it for the Action SDK](https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk/). All you need to do is [prepare your actions.json file and deploy it](https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk/create-a-project#create_an_action_package) using the `gactions` command.